# Simple SQL query is taking too long to respond

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing an issue in my SQL server 2008 R2 version previously it was good on executing everything. But from 2 days it not even responding for a small select queries. I didn't do any update or changed any thing but it is now throwing an issue and I couldn't find where is the issue.

I have a table which contains record count of 36 581.
When I am write the simple select query for that table:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE NAME]
```

It is showing the first 152 records and after that it is not showing any record but taking soo much time which I can say as infinite time as I have seen the time elapsed is around 30 minutes but there is no records extra showed in the result query except those 152 which shown at first.

Comment: Does the table contain a blob or other large field data type?

Comment: This sounds like a database problem, not a problem with your query or code.  I'm voting to move to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds like you have an open transaction locking rows hanging about.

Comment: Is this database on your local machine or is it over the network. If you do see the first 152 rows in the result window in ssms, then Martin may be right, there may be some row locking going on.

Comment: i think you haven't closed uncommitted transaction,check with input buffer and close the session or you have set DBCC Count ON

Answer (score 3):

Try running DBCC CHECKDB on your database like

```
DBCC CHECKDB('@databasename')
```